# Write one set of jQuery code for two textboxes

Tags: jquery

so I have two textboxes that I want to operate in the same way.
This is the code, which tells the textboxes to adjust their width according to the text entered:

```
$("#text1").keyup(function(){  
    var myLength = $("#text1").val().length;
    var widthNum = ((myLength+0.25)*30);
    if (myLength == 0) {
        $("#text1").animate({ width: 65 }, 'fast');
    }
    else {
        $("#text1").animate({ width: widthNum }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

I want to have `$("#text2")` to have the same properties with the same line of code. In other words, I don't want to write another 10 or so lines. Is there any way I can include both textboxes in the same set of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use ID's to identify dom elements unless they are unique, an ID must be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give both `input` elements the same class, then you can select them by that class. Within the event handler you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the event. Try this:

```
$(".text").keyup(function(){  
    var widthNum = ($(this).val().length + 0.25) * 30;
    $(this).animate({ width: myLength == 0 ? 65 : widthNum }, 'fast');
});
```

Comment: Aha! Thanks, man. I'll give you the answer in 8 mins. It might've been obvious to you, but thanks for helping out an inexperienced programmer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can just refer to both textboxes by their IDs, and use `this` to have the code refer to the one textbox being interacted with:

```
$("#text1, #text2").keyup(function(){  
    var myLength = $(this).val().length;
    var widthNum = ((myLength+0.25)*30);
    if (myLength == 0) {
        $(this).animate({ width: 65 }, 'fast');
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({ width: widthNum }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = function(e){
                //code here
             };

$("#text1").keyup(x);

$("#text2").keyup(x);
```

Bonus: you can also use

```
$(e) // instead of $("#text1") or $("#text2") to get the calling DOM element
```

Comment: The part he doesn't know how to do is what you hid with `//code here`.

Comment: I am on a phone... Laptop's at repair shop

Answer (score 0):

Give them a unique class name like `.my-special-textboxes` and instead of `$('#text1')` use `$(.my-special-textboxes')` and this wil lwork for any number of textboxes as long as they have this classname

```js
$('.my-special-textboxes').keyup(function() {
  var myLength = $(this).val().length;
  var widthNum = ((myLength + 0.25) * 30);
  if (myLength == 0) {
    $(this).animate({ width: 65 }, 'fast');
  } else {
    $(this).animate({ width: widthNum }, 'fast');
  }
});
```

Where `$(this)` represents the textbox that is being typed into